# Adding the below layout code dynamically in android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have implemented a layout statically in Android layouts folder xml file which is as follows

```
            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:weightSum="1.0"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:background="#ffef1128"
                    >


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/textbox12"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:text="20%"
                        android:background="@color/fund_background_blue"
                        android:textColor="@color/gen_text_color"
                         />
                     </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".25"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    >


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView22"
                        android:text="12.4"
                        android:layout_weight=".15"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />


                     <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_up"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight=".05"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
```

How can i add these programatically in Activity instead of xml Layout.as it involves layout weight and weight sum.

sample output for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can get instance from all widget and set Layout programmatically like this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.weight=1;

    your_widget.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: LinearLayout linLayout1=new LinearLayout(this);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams linLayoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linLayoutParams1.weight = 0.75f;

        //adding weight sum for linear layout1
        linLayout1.setWeightSum(1.0f);
 
          linLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
          linLayout1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
          linLayout1.setLayoutParams(linLayoutParams1);
 
Bro Actually i tried some thing like the code shared but was getting output empty